# Error while using CUDA and C++11

Tags: c++, gcc, cuda, c++11

I am using CUDA 4.1 and GCC 4.5 ... (FINALLY! CUDA supports GCC 4.5, but still waiting for GCC 4.6). Anyways, is it possible to use C++11 with the CUDA 4.1?

I tried passing:

```
--compiler-options "-std=c++0x"
```

to nvcc and it throws a bunch of errors at me:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.5/exception_ptr.h(100): error: copy constructor for class "std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr" may not have a parameter of type "std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr"

/usr/include/c++/4.5/exception_ptr.h(100): error: expected a ")"

/usr/include/c++/4.5/exception_ptr.h(110): error: expected a ")"

/usr/include/c++/4.5/exception_ptr.h(132): error: identifier "type_info" is undefined

/usr/include/c++/4.5/exception_ptr.h(101): error: identifier "__o" is undefined

/usr/include/c++/4.5/exception_ptr.h(112): error: expected a ">"

/usr/include/c++/4.5/exception_ptr.h(112): error: identifier "__o" is undefined

/usr/include/c++/4.5/nested_exception.h(62): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.5/nested_exception.h(64): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.5/nested_exception.h(77): error: member function "std::nested_exception::~nested_exception" may not be redeclared outside its class

/usr/include/c++/4.5/nested_exception.h(77): error: function "std::<error>" may not be initialized

/usr/include/c++/4.5/nested_exception.h(77): error: expected an expression

/usr/include/c++/4.5/nested_exception.h(82): error: expected a ")"

/usr/include/c++/4.5/nested_exception.h(110): error: expected a ")"

/usr/include/c++/4.5/nested_exception.h(115): error: expected a ")"

/usr/include/c++/4.5/nested_exception.h(122): error: expected a ")"

/usr/include/c++/4.5/nested_exception.h(127): error: expected a ")"

/usr/include/c++/4.5/nested_exception.h(127): error: function template "std::__throw_with_nested" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/cpp_type_traits.h(180): error: identifier "char16_t" is undefined

/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/cpp_type_traits.h(187): error: identifier "char32_t" is undefined

/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/cpp_type_traits.h(187): error: class "std::__is_integer<<error-type>>" has already been defined

21 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00000ef2_00000000-4_test_cuda.cpp1.ii".
```

Example test.cu

```
#include <cuda.h>

__host__ void test() {
  // nothing in method
}
```

Compiles fine with:

```
nvcc -c -o test.o test.cu
```

But not with C++0x

```
nvcc -c -o test.o test.cu --compiler-options "-std=c++0x"
```

Comment: Is it just the compiler option that causes the problems, or are you using specific c++0x features?

Comment: my test_cuda.cu has no code. It only has one function thats like test_cuda() {}

Comment: nope. didnt use extern "C" .. compiling C++ code.

Comment: You have to add some code to your answer. It is very difficult to know what is going wrong only by looking the error log.

Comment: Check my solution with CUDA 6:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941117/c11-standard-with-cuda-6-0

Answer (score 26):

No, as of this answer, `nvcc` does not support c++11 constructs, even if they are supported by the host compiler.

The reason it isn't as simple as passing `-std=c++0x` to the host compiler is that `nvcc` has to parse the entirety of the code in order to split it into its `__host__`and `__device__` halves. This preprocess happens before the host compiler is presented with any code at all, so `nvcc`'s parser needs to be able to grok c++11 for it to work.

Comment: thanks. do you have any suggestions on "proper" way to split up C++0x and CUDA code then?

Comment: Unfortunately, for now you need to quarantine everything CUDA into .cu files which only use c++03 constructs which ```nvcc``` can understand. Everything else goes into a .cpp file for your host compiler.

Comment: @JaredHoberock hasn't it been changed in past two years with newer CUDA versions?

Comment: @Farzad, apparently not, since exactly this same error brought me here today.

Comment: smart ptrs, tr1::unordered_map... I miss these basic features badly... Has anyone tried to compile .cu with some old Boost releases?

Answer (score 11):

Update on @Jared Hoberock's answer based on another message he posted on [Thrust's Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thrust-users/R37GIkMG4tk): it seems that C++11 support has been added to CUDA 6.5 (although it is still experimental and undocumented).

#### Dummy example: `test.cu`

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>

__host__ void test() {
  float a = 12.;
  double b = 3.;
  auto c = a * b;
  std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

#### Compilation & execution

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 test.cu -o test
$ ./test
36
```

Without `-std=c++11`, I get the following (expected) error:

```
test.cu(7): error: explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)
```

Note: this example may fail to compile with [GCC 5.1](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/836068/cuda-programming-and-performance/-bug-incompatibility-with-c-11-standard/).

### Update

CUDA 7.0 [officially](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/power-cpp11-cuda-7/) introduced C++11 support:

> CUDA 7 adds C++11 feature support to nvcc, the CUDA C++ compiler. This means that you can use C++11 features not only in your host code compiled with nvcc, but also in device code. New C++ language features include auto, lambda functions, variadic templates, static_assert, rvalue references, range-based for loops, and more. To enable C++11 support, pass the flag --std=c++11 to nvcc (this option is not required for Microsoft Visual Studio).

Comment: In my case, when I try to compile this I get `nvcc warning : The -c++11 flag is not supported with the configured host compiler. Flag will be ignored.`. This happens with version 4.6 of g++, not with version 4.8. My Cuda version is 7.0

Comment: @julianromera you need a host compiler that supports `-std=c++11`, and this is not the case of g++ 4.6. However, this version of g++ supports `-std=c++0x`, but in `nvcc`'s help, you can read `Allowed values for this option:  'c++11'.`, so I don't know if you will be able to use C++11 features unless you upgrade your compiler.