# Which g++ version is used by different nvcc versions?

Tags: cuda, g++, nvcc

Initially we wrote plenty of code in C++ 11 however cuda 5.5 doesnt support various c++11 constructs. Is there a reference to which is the g++ version that different versions nvcc use, specifically for cuda 5.5 or cuda 6??

Comment: You may not be asking the right question. I use `gcc` 4.8.2 (not officially supported for CUDA 5.5), but this does not mean that I can use C++11 features with `nvcc` blindly. This may be a duplicate of: [c++ version supported by cuda 5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073828/c-version-supported-by-cuda-5-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a list of compilers supported by the CUDA toolchain in every copy of the documentation - for example [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/#linux-5-5) for CUDA 5.5 on linux.

At the moment, the release versions of gcc 4.7 shipped with Ubuntu, Fedora and OpenSuSe are the most recent compiler version supported with the CUDA 5.5 release toolkit.