# std::isnan has not been declared, with g++-5

Tags: c++, gcc, cuda, nvcc

I'm trying to compile my program with nvcc and g++-5 and I get this error.

```
In file included from /usr/include/glm/detail/func_common.hpp:426:0,
             from /usr/include/glm/detail/func_geometric.inl:5,
             from /usr/include/glm/detail/func_geometric.hpp:113,
             from /usr/include/glm/geometric.hpp:6,
             from /usr/include/glm/detail/func_matrix.inl:4,
             from /usr/include/glm/detail/func_matrix.hpp:149,
             from /usr/include/glm/detail/type_mat2x2.inl:4,
             from /usr/include/glm/detail/type_mat2x2.hpp:182,
             from /usr/include/glm/mat2x2.hpp:6,
             from /usr/include/glm/glm.hpp:71,
             from src/controls.cpp:6:
/usr/include/glm/detail/func_common.inl:623:14: error: ‘std::isnan’   has not been declared
   using std::isnan;
          ^
/usr/include/glm/detail/func_common.inl:659:14: error: ‘std::isinf’ has not been declared
   using std::isinf;
```

Using g++ it compiles correctly, but nvcc required g++-5. Does anyone know how to solve this? By the way, this started happening once I ran `sudo do-release-upgrade` on Ubuntu.

`nvcc --version` output is this:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

`g++-5 --version` output is this:

```
g++-5 (Ubuntu 5.5.0-1ubuntu1) 5.4.1 20171010
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

`g++ --version` output is this:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) 7.2.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I'm compiling with c++11 and cmath is not included in my source files. This is my `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/gcc-5 CACHE PATH "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/gcc-5 CACHE PATH "" FORCE)
project(cpu_pcd C CXX CUDA)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

file(GLOB SRC src/*.cpp src/*.hpp)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

include_directories(src/)
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})

cuda_add_library(kernel src/update_particles.cu)
cuda_add_executable(cpu_pcd ${SRC})

set_target_properties(cpu_pcd
  PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION on)

target_link_libraries(cpu_pcd kernel)
target_link_libraries(cpu_pcd ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} glfw  ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested I solved it changing two lines of `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/gcc-5 CACHE PATH "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++ CACHE PATH "" FORCE)
```

Now it compiles correctly, thanks to all willing to help.

Comment: I use gcc4.9 where I can find this file exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `nvcc` to run host C++ compiler in `C++11` mode (passing this option to gcc directly is not enough):

```
 nvcc -Xcompiler "-std=c++11"
```

details can be found [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/745106/nvcc-c-11-standard-in-cuda-frontend-dependencies-gcc-windows-vs-linux-/)

Related information:

[c++ version supported by cuda 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073828/c-version-supported-by-cuda-5-0)

[Error while using CUDA and C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057123/error-while-using-cuda-and-c11)

Comment: I tried that, not working. Also tried this ``nvcc -std=c++11 src/*.cpp -o main -lpthread -lGL -lGLEW``.

Comment: Enable verbose mode in cmake an check what parameters are passed to nvcc

Comment: You may also want to enable verbose mode for `nvcc` itself to check how it calls g++.

Comment: Seems like it fails compiling before calling nvcc. The command called before the error pops up is ``/usr/bin/g++-5  -DGLFW_DLL -I/home/dev/work/octree-cpu-pcd/src  -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/cpu_pcd.dir/src/controls.cpp.o -c /home/dev/work/octree-cpu-pcd/src/controls.cpp``

Comment: Check version of `/usr/bin/gcc-5` and try to compile simple program with `std::isnan` with it directly. You need to fix that and that is unrelated to nvcc and CUDA.

Comment: Changed it to compile with g++-5 btw.

Comment: ok, with g++ it compiles correctly. But nvcc supports only g++-5, any suggestion?

Comment: "any suggestion?" fix g++-5

Answer (score 1):

std::isnan and std::isinf declared in `<cmath>` starting with C++11.  Is that header included?  Is the compile done in C++11 or later mode?